# $modal and ui.bootstrap doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am a beginner trying to implement $uibmodal but not only am I not able to get the modal to work, adding ui-bootstrap and $uibmodal stops the rest of the code from working.
When I added a dependency 'ui.bootstrap' below, the page doesn't load (when I remove it, the page loads as normal)

```
`angular
  .module('navApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.bootstrap'

  ])
```

Then in my controller, when I included $uibmodal, scope.title doesn't show up in my view etc

```
angular.module('navApp')
// Passing the $modal to controller as dependency
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibmodal', function
($scope, $uibmodal) {
$scope.title = "Hello, Angm-Generator!";
$scope.open = function () {
var modalInstance = $uibmodal.open({
templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
controller: 'ModalCtrl'
});
};
}])
```

The error msg I got is angular.js:13550 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibmodalProvider <- $uibmodal <- HomeCtrl

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $uibModal with the capital M?

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .factory('modalFactory', function($uibModal) {
      //Stuff
    }
```

Comment: That worked, thanks very much! Only problem left is that my dismiss modal code doest seem to work (when I click button to close modal, nothing happens.) I will create a new post for this..